# iOS in-app-purchase receipt: what does it look like?

Tags: ios, storekit

SKPaymentTransaction transactionReceipt

I've been trying to NSLog the receipt, but Apple's test user system is broken at the moment. Does anyone have an example of what it looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my receipt info (some stuff is removed for security purposes)

> ```
> "latest_receipt_info" =     {
>     bid = "YOURBIDGOESHERE";
>     bvrs = "1.0";
>     "expires_date" = 1321356708000;
>     "expires_date_formatted" = "2011-11-15 11:31:48 Etc/GMT";
>     "item_id" = SOMEIDGOESHERE;
>     "original_purchase_date" = "2011-11-15 11:21:40 Etc/GMT";
>     "original_transaction_id" = SOMENUMERICCODE;
>     "product_id" = SOMEPRODUCTID;
>     "purchase_date" = "2011-11-15 11:26:48 Etc/GMT";
>     quantity = 1;
>     "transaction_id" = SOMENUMERICCODE;
> };
> receipt =     {
>     bid = "YOURBIDHERE";
>     bvrs = "1.0";
>     "expires_date" = 1321356398234;
>     "expires_date_formatted" = "2011-11-15 11:26:38 Etc/GMT";
>     "item_id" = SOMEIDGOESHERE;
>     "original_purchase_date" = "2011-11-15 11:21:40 Etc/GMT";
>     "original_transaction_id" = SOMENUMERICCODE;
>     "product_id" = SOMEPRODUCTID;
>     "purchase_date" = "2011-11-15 11:21:38 Etc/GMT";
>     quantity = 1;
>     "transaction_id" = SOMENUMERICCODE;
> };
> ```

Sometimes you get "latest_expired_receipt_info".

One thing to be aware of is that sometimes the expired date is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction;
// state of transaction:
int state = transaction.transactionState; // can be equal to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing || SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed || SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased || SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored
// corresponding product id
NSString *prId = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
```

For more information, look here : [SKPaymentTransaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I'm actually wondering if anyone knows what the string output of the receipt looks like.